# @ wire returning undefined for both data and error

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I have the following js code : -

```
export default class MapContact extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '0035g000007MUTlAAO', fields: [NAME_FIELD, ADD_FIELD] })
    contact
    getData() {
        console.log(this.contact);
        console.log(1221);
    }
}
```

and this is the html : -

```
<template>
    <button onclick={getData}>A button</button>
</template>
```

this.contact gives undefined.
Is there anything wrong with this code ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have the necessary imports in place. If not,

```
import { getRecord,  getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
```

getFieldValue is optional.
And try the updated code -

```
export default class MapContact extends LightningElement {
        @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '0035g000007MUTlAAO', fields: [NAME_FIELD, ADD_FIELD] })
        contact
        getData() {
            console.log(this.contact.data); //Change here
            console.log(1221);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Aditya Also hope you are importing `wire` in js file